# Dictate vs Instruct (Which context or vibe it used for?)

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I recently found the word "dictate". As always, I dived into the dictionary and took a look for definition. Following is what I found.

> ***Dictate***
> to give orders, or tell someone exactly what they must do, with total authority

(from Cambridge Dictionary)

At the moment I saw this definition, the word "instruct" directly came to my mind and I was a bit confused. So, I searched for definition of "instruct".

Dictionary told me

> ***Instruct***
> to order or tell someone to do something, especially in a formal way

Two words seems interchangeable for me! So I googled "dictate vs instruct" sort of things. However, I could not able to find any useful information: usually means they are used in very different situation.

What are the difference  between them and what situations and mood or vibe they are typically used respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dictate for authoritative commands, emphasis on authority. Use instruct for educational descriptions of processes, emphasis on making expectations clear.

**Dictate** has two general uses: either A) to issue decrees in an authoritarian manner, or B) to speak words that are intended to be transcribed by another person.

A dictator is [(MW.com)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dictator):

> 1a : a person granted absolute emergency power especially, history : one appointed by the senate (see senate sense 1b) of ancient Rome

> b : one holding complete autocratic control : a person with unlimited governmental power

> c : one ruling in an absolute ... and often oppressive way fascist dictators

> 2 : one who says or reads something for a person to transcribe or for a machine to record : one that dictates...

**Instruct** carries more of a sense of teaching or guiding someone about how they are expected to perform a task.

An instructor is [(Mw.com)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/instructor) "one that instructs : teacher."

Comment: Helped a lot! Thank you so much.

Comment: Not quite true, at least in UK English. Here I have to "instruct" a lawyer to act for me in certain matters like house purchase. If I do that I am certainly not teaching them anything, I am commissioning them to do work for which they are qualified but I am not. Also I don't "direct" them because I am a client, not a superior.

Comment: **dictate** has another general meaning: *to require or determine necessarily,* e.g., *The weather will dictate how long we stay,* and *Injuries dictated the choice of players.* (m-w)